# Jackson Serialization sometimes borking with timezone

Tags: json, grails, jackson

(I am in the UTC+2 timezone, which I assume is the 2 hour difference).

I'm busy writing a JSON RESTful API that's part of a Grails application (2.0.3 on this project in particular, but this problem occurs in other versions). I use Jackson for Serialization and Deserialization of Json, and the JsonService's configuration looks like this: http://pastebin.com/JacytMuF

So multiple Domain objects have values collated and represented in a single DTO (in this case it's a simple map), and these are just passed to the JsonService to convert to Json, which is returned (to a request). All of the fields are serialized correctly, with the exception of two of the (several) Dates, which are off by 2 hours. I can for example run:

```
  db_dev=# select next_billing_date from account where code = 'CATS001';
  next_billing_date  
---------------------
 2013-06-20 00:00:00
```

and this is verified to be correct (within memory) by this little action

```
def checkTimezone() {
        Account acc = Account.findByCode("CATS001")
        log.error(acc.nextBillingDate)
    }
```

which returns

```
ERROR mash.TestController  - 2013-06-20 00:00:00.0
```

as expected. Furthermore, I can check that nothing tampers with the in-memory value by doing, within the RestAccountController:

```
def show() {
         ...
         def ans = [ code: ac.code, nextBillingDate: ac.nextBillingDate ] 
         log.error("CATTTTSSSSSSSSSSSSSS::::: ${ac.nextBillingDate}")
         [ans: ans]
    }
```

(returning)

```
ERROR mash.RestAccountController  - CATTTTSSSSSSSSSSSSSS::::: 2013-06-20 00:00:00.0
```

Yet when I hit the relevant endpoint, I get:

```
nextBillingDate": "2013-06-19T22:00:00.000+0000"
```

Which is off by 2 hours. The nextBillingDate property is a normal Java Date object, the underlying database is psql:

```
next_billing_date           | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain    |
```

And hence I am a bit lost for ideas on why it's randomly deducting 2 hours. I can see why 2 hours is the magic number (timezone differences), but I cannot explain *why* it's offsetting the Date on some objects (or indeed only on some subset of the Date objects).

Comment: Have a look at this, if it is source of any inspiration: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734768/jqgrid-date-formatter-not-applying-local-time-offset-correctly-grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734768/jqgrid-date-formatter-not-applying-local-time-offset-correctly-grails)

Comment: I suggest you to use the same `SimpleDateFormat` that you declared in your `JsonService` to print your debugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to check:

1. Is your JVM set to UTC timezone by default?
2. Is the timezone in database row UTC? In your case I don't think db cares about timezone.

**Option:**

If JVM is set to UTC by default then, you would see the offset of 2 hours. In order get the timestap in your zone which is `UTC+2:00` you can set the default timezone to your zone by like below in `Bootstrap.groovy`

`TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2:00"))`

**Note:-** Refer [GMT vs UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292334/difference-between-utc-and-gmt-standard-time-in-net) to find the difference.